# Rails: View ActiveRecord's resulting query

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

ActiveRecord's query interface seems for me sometimes very complex and not intuitive. Is there a possibility to view in which SQL query results Rails construction I have written?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look in the console with the web server running, you will see what the ActiveRecord queries are compiled into. Additionally, you can open up the Rails console (`rails console`) and inspect them manually.